# How to access refreshView() in Twitter Bootstrap Datepicker for Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

**EDIT** It actually does it right out of the box.

I leave the plunker here just in case someone drops in via search: http://plnkr.co/edit/maArVIu6iWuWZbkvLI4j?p=preview

I need to disable disable specific dates in a datepicker based on user input.

The datepicker offers isDisabled(date) but that only gets fired once. It does however have a refreshView() as per: https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/779

What I can't figure out is how to trigger it after a change.

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="plunker">
  <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.8/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.10.0.js"></script>
    <script src="example.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div ng-controller="DatepickerDemoCtrl" >
      <h4>Inline</h4>
      <div style="display:inline-block; min-height:290px;">
        <div class="well well-sm" ng-model="dt" ng-change="change()">
            <datepicker></datepicker>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

and the js

```
angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);
var DatepickerDemoCtrl = function ($scope) {
  $scope.change = function(){
    console.log('changed to ' + $scope.dt);
    // Get array of disabled dates
    // call refreshView(); <--- My problem, right here
  };
};
```

I've ommitted the part where I define an array of disabled dates and the isDisabled function that checks against that. What I only need to know is how to trigger the refreshView()

EDIT:

This is what I want to call/trigger in ui-bootstrap-tpls.js

```
  this.refreshView = function() {
    if ( this.element ) {
      this._refreshView();

      var date = ngModelCtrl.$modelValue ? new Date(ngModelCtrl.$modelValue) : null;
      ngModelCtrl.$setValidity('date-disabled', !date || (this.element && !this.isDisabled(date)));
    }
  };
```

Comment: How did you fix this? How do you get access to an object with `refreshView()`?

Comment: Hey, I actually build my own date picker component in the end. Took about a day to implement that and all the features I needed.

If you need some pointers on how to do what let me know. Good luck!